# How to render view usin Laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

[image]I am trying to create simple application using Laraver(8) Blade, I am a complete beginner in Blade, I want to rednder extended view in my template, but it doesn't works, also it doesn't throwing any errors, The page is refreshed my view not showing, what i am doing wrong?

main layout:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    @include('layout.header')
    @stack('css')
    </head>
    <body id="body">
    <div class="blackscreen"></div>
    <div class="blackscreen2"></div>
    @yield('content')
    <script src="{{url('js/developer.js')}}"></script>
    @stack('js')
    </body>
    </html>
```

template:

```html
@extends('layout.main')
@section('content')
    <h1>hello</h1>
@endsection
```

route:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('layout/main');
    });

    Route::get('/test2', function () {
        return view('layout/main');
    });
```

this is my file structure

Comment: Try using dot notation when returning view scripts from your routes. Like so: `return view('layout.main');`

Comment: seems, not working :/

Comment: Could you give us some more code examples? It isn't clear what's the path of your `template.blade.php`.

Comment: I think the problem you're having is that you are trying to return the `resources/views/layout/main.blade.php`, when instead you should be returning the `resources/views/path/to/template.blade.php` like so: `return view('path.to.template');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you save your template into resources/views/template.blade.php,
you should call view method like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('template');
});
```

if you save your template into other folder inside resources/views, like resources/views/test/template.blade.php,
you should call view method like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('test.template');
});
```